# Generating and inserting html with javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
<script>
    function generateHtml(index)
    {
       document.write('Hello ' + index);
    }
</script>
```

and I have a server side script generating the following html

```
<div><script>generateHtml(3)</script></div>
<div><script>generateHtml(4)</script></div>
```

in the hopes that `Hello 3` and `Hello 4` would be written in the page. However, this does not occur. Instead nothing is displayed. What is wrong with this approach?

Is it better to wrap the `<div>`'s is a id that can be selected and then change the html instead of writing to the DOM?

Comment: Why are you using this approach? you can generate htmls directly by server side scripts

Comment: True. The reason is that this only represent the persisted state. In my application there are two states (free and occupied), and there will be some ajax to change between the states. By having this done by javascript, I hope to avoid duplicating the html for the two states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your code to work you must ensure that the html is present on the page after the javascript function

```
<body>
   <script>
       function generateHtml(index)
       {
           document.write('Hello ' + index);
        }
  </script>

  <div><script>generateHtml(3)</script></div>
  <div><script>generateHtml(4)</script></div>

</body>
```

To answer your question, using id's to select the DOM elements is certainly a better option.

Maybe a suggestion, use an MVVM framework such as knockout/ember/backbone/angular to do any dynamic DOM manipulation.

Example in knockout here ---> http://jsfiddle.net/x0t8dxzw/

Comment: I will go for the selector solution instead I think. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the `<script>` containing function `generateHtml` is added after the other `<script>`blocks, causing

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: generateHtml is not defined
```

Make sure it's added beforehand so that [it works as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/2cttLbjr/).

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. It turned out that I had a "text/javascript" in my code (which I omitted for the demonstration) that appeared to cause the problem.,